# Adding an existing user to a group with puppet

Tags: linux, redhat, puppet, user-management, user-accounts

Is it possible to add an existing user to a group with puppet 2.7.18?

We have two modules, each one defines one class :

- module "user" creates all users, including user foo and user bar.
- module "subversion" deals with various conf files and creates group svn.

We would like to add user foo to group svn inside module "subversion".

I've tried the membership parameter as described in [the existing feature request](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/7241):

```
group {
"svn":
    ensure  => present,
    gid     => xxxxx;
}
user {
"foo":
    group      => ["svn"],
    membership => minimum;
}
```

But I get the following error :

> err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
>   SERVER: Duplicate declaration: User[foo] is already declared in file
>   /pathto/modules/subversion/manifests/init.pp at line xx; cannot
>   redeclare at /pathto/modules/users/manifests/init.pp:xxx on node
>   myserver.example.com

Is this feature is already implemented? If not, is there a good workaround?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you declare users as [virtual resources](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_virtual.html) , you can then use 'realize' or the collection syntax ( User <| ... |>). Here's an example:

```
@user { 'foo':
  groups     => ['somegroup'],
  membership => minimum,
}
```

Then realize that virtual user with then collection syntax:

```
User <| title == foo |>
```

And elsewhere you can add to the parameters for that virtual resource using plusignment:

```
User <| title == foo |> { groups +> "svn" }
```

Comment: So I guess there's no alternative except virtual ressources at this time :( Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: There is a typo or attribute changed between Puppet versions: It is not group but groups (plural). Using Puppet 3.2.2

Comment: can someone expand on this with a short example.

Answer (score 23):

Using Puppet virtual resources is the right way to do it - but if you can't change the user definitions and need a workaround fix meanwhile, the following is horrible and hacky, but will work:

```
exec { 'foo somegroup membership':
  unless  => '/bin/grep -q "somegroup\\S*foo" /etc/group',
  command => '/sbin/usermod -aG somegroup foo',
  require => User['foo'],
}
```

Essentially we just check if somegroup contains user foo yet... if not, use the normal usermod commands to add it in addition to the existing groups that foo belongs to.

Comment: Puppet might riquire fully qualified paths to the executables. Edited to reflect this.

Comment: Horrible & hacky, but really helpful. I was hoping not to have to learn a new language construct to do something a conceptually simple as adding a user to a group.

Comment: Perhaps a more proper (while still being hacky of course) way would be to use `getent group somegroup|cut -d: -f4|grep -q foo` to not assume we're using `/etc/group`.

Comment: Super helpful - thanks. I had to change the "unless" and "usermod" to include the full path as follow: 
unless => "/user/bin/grep..."
command => "/user/bin/usermod..."

Comment: For @jnpWebDeveloper and those like them: as per the [documentation](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-path), you can specify a `path` parameter as well. I suggest having a global resource default, perhaps that pulls in `$PATH` from facter.

Comment: If we're going to implement portable ugly hacks, I'd be inclined to use `id -nG foo | grep somegroup`, as an environment using LDAP or similar could potentially have both local and remote groups with the same name.  getent generally only returns the first one, which might miss some.  Also, primary group membership isn't always in /etc/group, so one needs to check the gid field in /etc/passwd as well.  Or just use id (or groups), which does all that work for you. :)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks - ugly hack for sure, but it gets the job done.  Here's a pathed example (combining the above comments) to add 'nrpe' to the 'nagios' group.  I used a package require as the user here is RPM provided rather than by puppet.

```
  exec {"nrpe nagios membership":
    unless => "/bin/getent group nagios|/bin/cut -d: -f4|/bin/grep -q nrpe",
    command => "/usr/sbin/usermod -a -G nagios nrpe",
    require => Package['nrpe'],
  }
```